# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception, android-sqlite

When I am trying to execute this app I am receiving this error. I don't know why I am receiving this error. When creating the table, does it leave it empty or try to fill it with values to start because my app uses the EasyModbusJava library and requires a slave ID to connect which I am not passing and I am not expecting it to be able to connect currently. If this is just a issue with the creation with the table what changes do I need to make?

> 08-21 13:31:48.342 8821-8821/? E/Zygote: v2
>   08-21 13:31:48.344 8821-8821/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>   08-21 13:31:49.407 8821-8821/com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "Rooms": syntax error
>   08-21 13:31:49.418 8821-8821/com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms, PID: 8821
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms/com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms.OverviewListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Rooms": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table Float Rooms(_id integer primary key autoincrement, slave ID, room name)
>                                                                                    #################################################################
>                                                                                    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                                    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                                       (near "Rooms": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table Float Rooms(_id integer primary key autoincrement, slave ID, room name))
>                                                                                    #################################################################
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>                                                                                     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Rooms": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table Float Rooms(_id integer primary key autoincrement, slave ID, room name)
>                                                                                    #################################################################
>                                                                                    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                                    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                                       (near "Rooms": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table Float Rooms(_id integer primary key autoincrement, slave ID, room name))
>                                                                                    #################################################################
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1005)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:570)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1976)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1907)
>                                                                                        at com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms.database.FloatBaseHelper.onCreate(FloatBaseHelper.java:23)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
>                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>                                                                                        at com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms.FloatLab.(FloatLab.java:35)
>                                                                                        at com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms.FloatLab.get(FloatLab.java:28)
>                                                                                        at com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms.OverviewListFragment.updateUI(OverviewListFragment.java:45)
>                                                                                        at com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms.OverviewListFragment.onCreateView(OverviewListFragment.java:34)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>   08-21 13:31:49.418 8821-8821/com.wavefloatrooms.wavefloatrooms E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6929)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
>                                                                                           ... 9 more

```
public class FloatBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "floatBase.db";

    public FloatBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + RoomTable.NAME + "(" +
            "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + RoomTable.Cols.SLAVE_ID +
            ", " + RoomTable.Cols.ROOM_NAME + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

public class FloatRoomCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {

    public FloatRoomCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public FloatRoom getFloatRoom(){
        int slaveID = getInt(getColumnIndex(RoomTable.Cols.SLAVE_ID));
        String roomName = getString(getColumnIndex(RoomTable.Cols.ROOM_NAME));
        FloatRoom room = new FloatRoom(slaveID);
        room.setRoomName(roomName);

        return room;
    }
}

    public class OverviewListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRoomRecyclerView;
    private RoomAdapter mAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_list, container, false);

        mRoomRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.floatroom_recylerview);
        mRoomRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        FloatLab floatlab = FloatLab.get(getActivity());
        List<FloatRoom> rooms = floatlab.getFloatRooms();

        if(mAdapter == null){
            mAdapter = new RoomAdapter(rooms);
            mRoomRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }else{
            mAdapter.setFloatRooms(rooms);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class RoomHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView mTimeRemainingTextView;
        private TextView mRoomNameTextView;
        private ImageButton mControlPanelBtn;
        private ProgressBar mTimeProgressBar;

        private FloatRoom mFloatRoom;

        public RoomHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_floatroom, parent, false));
            initializeVariables();
        }

        private void initializeVariables() {
            mTimeRemainingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_remaining_textView);
            mRoomNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_name_textView);
            mControlPanelBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.control_panel_btn);
            mTimeProgressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }

        public void bind(FloatRoom room) {
            mFloatRoom = room;
            mRoomNameTextView.setText(mFloatRoom.getRoomName());
            mTimeRemainingTextView.setText("Time Remaining: " + mFloatRoom.getSessionTimeRemaining() + " minutes");
            mControlPanelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startControlPanel();
        }

        private void startControlPanel() {
            Intent intent;
            switch (mFloatRoom.getRoomType()){
                case 0:
                    intent = new StandardRoomActivity().newIntent(getActivity(), mFloatRoom.getSlaveID());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new EliteRoomActivity().newIntent(getActivity(), mFloatRoom.getSlaveID());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR Starting Auto mode!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    }

    private class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomHolder> {

        private List<FloatRoom> mRooms;

        public RoomAdapter(List<FloatRoom> rooms){
            mRooms = rooms;
        }

        @Override
        public RoomHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            return new RoomHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RoomHolder holder, int position) {
            FloatRoom room = mRooms.get(position);
            holder.bind(room);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mRooms.size();
        }

        public void setFloatRooms(List<FloatRoom> rooms){
            mRooms = rooms;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RoomTable.NAME` would appear to be `Float Rooms`. You cannot have a space in a table name. Rename this to something else that does not have a space in it.

Comment: Well, you actually **can** have a space in a table (or a column) name, if you surround the table name with special markers, such as `[` and `]`. i.e.: `[Float Rooms]` is a legit name (the special markers won't appear as part of the name, you only have to use them in queries and commands). It's not an encouraged practice, though. Better use an underscore (`_`) instead of a space.